# Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column when try to create a View

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to create a view from my tables. 
When I create a view like this from 1 table it works nice:

```
CREATE VIEW v2 AS
    SELECT section_id, section_name,  count(*) AS num, count(*) as num1
    FROM section_of_science
    GROUP BY section_id;

select * from v2;
```

But when I try to create a view from two tables it doesn't work:

```
CREATE VIEW v3 AS
    SELECT section_of_science.section_id, section_of_science. section_name,
           scientific_areas.areas_name,  count(*) AS num, count(*) as num1
    FROM section_of_science,
         scientific_areas
    GROUP BY section_id;

select * from v3;
```

And I get this error:

> Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains
>   nonaggregated column 'Lab3.scientific_areas.areas_name' which is not
>   functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is
>   incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

what am I doing wrong?

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (**without errors**), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Tip 2: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first query works because you are aggregating by the primary key.  You are clearly learning SQL, so you should include *all* unaggregated columns in the `GROUP BY`.  Later you can learn about small efficiencies.

Your second should be written as:

```
SELECT ss.section_id, ss.section_name, ss.areas_name, count(*) AS num
FROM section_of_science ss join
     scientific_areas as
     ON -- JOIN CONDITIONS HERE
GROUP BY ss.section_id, ss.section_name, ss.areas_name;
```

Notes:

- Use meaningful table aliases (abbreviations for the table names).
- NEVER use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- ALWAYS use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.
- Your query is missing `ON` conditions for the `JOIN`.
- List all the unaggregated columns in the `GROUP BY`.